# How to compile libdvdcss on Mac with Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I am wondering how to compile the source code of libdvdcss using Xcode on Mac OS X? The file `bsdi_ioctl.c` has include statements for `/sys/dev/scsi/scsi.h` and `/sys/dev/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h`.

What I did is run `./bootstrap` and `./configure` to generate the `config.h` first, but I still got the problem.

Can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: The usual way is `./configure --prefix=whatever ; make ; make install`. Not every program follows this, but many do. If this fails, try cut-n-pasting details.

Comment: I was not talking about how to compile it on command line.

Comment: @sza: even if you're building with Xcode (which is probably a mistake, BTW, but maybe you have a good reason ?) you still need `./configure --prefix=whatever` from the command line beforehand.

Comment: I mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Can you give us some versions, so we know what you're using?

Comment: Can you show the exact commands you are running and output you are getting?

Comment: @sza Review the answers and either upvote or select the one that helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual that your Makefile will be trying to include those files as the autoconf file has an instruction to look for them before including them in your Makefile.  But whatever the reason, you have a couple options for compiling:

1. Edit src/Makefile.  Search for `$(bsdi_sources)` and delete all occurrences then re-make (do not reconfigure)
2. *or* Edit configure.ac.  Search for `AM_CONDITIONAL(SYS_BSDI` and replace with `SYS_BSDI='0'`.  Then re-run ./bootstrap & ./configure
3. *or* Run `SYS_BSDI="0" ./configure` (single command) to re-make without.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let the debug messages from `./configure` deceive you:

```
checking dvd.h usability... no
checking dvd.h presence... no
checking for dvd.h... no
checking /sys/dev/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h usability... no
checking /sys/dev/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h presence... no
checking for /sys/dev/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h... no
checking sys/scsi/scsi_types.h usability... no
checking sys/scsi/scsi_types.h presence... no
checking for sys/scsi/scsi_types.h... no
checking sys/scsi.h usability... no
checking sys/scsi.h presence... no
checking for sys/scsi.h... no
checking IOKit/storage/IODVDMediaBSDClient.h usability... yes
checking IOKit/storage/IODVDMediaBSDClient.h presence... yes
checking for IOKit/storage/IODVDMediaBSDClient.h... yes
```

This is what I got when building the library. Even though some messages might get you worried, some of these headers are not important for the Mac system. Anyway, I tried the following and everything worked ok. I'm currently using Mac OS X 10.6.7, and just to be clear, **libdvdcss must be build from the cmd-line**. Forget XCode!

The first step is downloading the most recent version of the library. If you check their [homepage](http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html), you'll notice they recommend downloading the sources directly from their SVN repository:

```
svn co svn://svn.videolan.org/libdvdcss/trunk libdvdcs
```

Once the download finishes and you are inside the directory, executing these commands should compile the library successfully:

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
```

If you want to test it there's an application named *csstest* inside the *test* directory. First, find where your DVD is mounted on (make sure you have a disk inside the computer):

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on /Volumes/DISK_NAME (udf, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

and then run *csstest*:

```
$ ./csstest /Volumes/DISK_NAME/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB 1024
cool, I found libdvdcss version 1.2.10
requested sector: 000001ba...30107f1c04e03100c031223e0c01017c86c08fff88ff...
sector is not scrambled
```

To install it on your system, you must have superuser access in order to execute:

```
make install
```